# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 with NVidia GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am performing a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 and have a Titan X Nvidia GPU card. Should I have the GPU plugged in while installing the new OS? I have tried without it plugged in (which works) but then when I plug it in afterwords I get a black screen.

I am aware of all the NVidia graphics issues and have tried many solutions to get it working but nothing seems to fix my black screen.

Comment: Have you tried with the nomodeset parameter?

Comment: nomodeset by typing f6 during installation

Comment: In my grub profile I set the option to "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset" but still get the black screen. Should I reinstall the OS with the GPU plugged in?